# Will the heap memory be released when do kill -9?

Tags: c++, c, linux

My program run on daemon mode. And if I do "kill -9" my program, I don't know exactly that the heap memory will be released automatically or else they are still there until we restart computer.

Please help me for consult. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The process is terminated and *everything* it has allocated is released.

Comment: Not always everything, unfortunately.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, could you provide examples? I'm assuming you're talking about things like file-handles and sockets?

Comment: @Cramer: Shared memory, for one. Also, resources belonging to another process that isn't listening for the death of the allocating process.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I really fail to see what resources belonging to another process have to do with the release of resources allocated by this process.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using shared memory (i.e. memory allocated via `shmget`, ...) you will get your memory freed. Shared memory behaves like a file, it stays reserved and accessible for further sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The program is allocated memory when it is running, some of that memory is used as heap. When you used force kill, the entire memory used by the program is freed and along with it the heap as well.